# is it possible to specify the github actions's lfs files checkout url

Tags: github-actions, git-lfs

I have tried to store the git lfs large files in a seperate location. Now when run the Github Actions, I want to pull the source from github, and the LFS files from the seperate location. this is how I set the github actions checkout right now:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        lfs: true
```

I have read the [official document](https://github.com/actions/checkout) and did not found how to set the LFS url when run the checkout in Github Actions. Is it possible to set the lfs location? like this:

```
jobs:
      build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v3
          with:
            lfs: true
            lfs-url: 'https://demo.com/lfs/info'
```